# Reload URL with param depending on value of dropdown

Tags: php, html, url, dropdown

I would like to reload an URL with special parameters when a selection in a dropdown is made. The actual result is, that the URL changes and I see the URL with the parameter in the browserbar, but the page does not really reload/refresh.

Thats the code where I fetch the sorttype param ... in fact a reload or refresh is not done, because other code is also not processed

```
// parse url
$url_components = parse_url($compurl); 
// get actual url path
$url = ltrim($url_components['path'], "/"); // ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/");
// get parameters from url
$sorttype = "";
parse_str($url_components['query'], $params); 
$sorttype = $params['sorttype'];
```

Thats the code where I place the dropdown

```
<!-- show sortoptions in dropdown-box with redirect on selection change -->
<form action="" method="post" style="float: right;">
    <strong>Sortierung:</strong>
    <select name="sortmode" onchange="location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value; "  style="margin-top:6px;">
       <option <?php if (isset($sorttype) && ($sorttype == 'Autor')) { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?php echo $url . '?sorttype=Autor' ?>">Autor</option>
       <option <?php if (isset($sorttype) && ($sorttype == 'Erscheinungsjahr')) { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?php echo $url . '?sorttype=Erscheinungsjahr' ?>">Erscheinungsjahr</option>
       <option <?php if (isset($sorttype) && ($sorttype == 'Herausgeber')) { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?php echo $url . '?sorttype=Herausgeber' ?>">Herausgeber</option>
       <option <?php if (isset($sorttype) && ($sorttype == 'Region')) { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?php echo $url . '?sorttype=Region' ?>">Region</option>
       <option <?php if (isset($sorttype) && ($sorttype == 'Titel')) { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?php echo $url . '?sorttype=Titel' ?>">Titel</option>
       <option <?php if (isset($sorttype) && ($sorttype == 'Stadt')) { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?php echo $url . '?sorttype=Stadt' ?>">Stadt</option>
       <option <?php if (isset($sorttype) && ($sorttype == 'Verlag')) { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?php echo $url . '?sorttype=Verlag' ?>">Verlag</option>
    </select> 
</form>
```

Comment: I suspect you are mixing POST and GET parameter passing. Using the form you can have POST parameters. Please read again the documentation like in http://zetcode.com/php/getpostrequest/

Comment: sorry ... i cannot figure out what the problem is ... and as far as i see the post and action settings for the form must not been set when i use the onchange event of the select tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple problems but the main is misunderstanding the `post` and `get`. When you want to use `post`, you don't change the url. You only need to reload the page with your variable set in `$_POST`. I have edited the code for minimal length:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <?php 
        print_r($_POST);
        #print it if want to see if it was set
        $sorttype = $_POST['sorttype']; #assign the var
        if (!isset($sorttype)){$sorttype="Not sorted";} #to overcome multiple checks
    ?>
</head>

<form action="" method="POST" style="float: left;">
    <strong>Sortierung:</strong>
    <select name="sorttype" style="margin-top:6px;" onchange="this.form.submit()">
       <option value="Foo" <?php if (($sorttype == 'Foo')) { echo 'selected'; } ?>>Foo</option>
       <option value="Bar" <?php if (isset($sorttype) && ($sorttype == 'Bar')) { echo 'selected'; } ?>>Bar</option>
       </select> 
</form>
</html>
```

Select name is the var name for post, selected has to be at the end before closing tag like this: `selected>`. `onchange` only needs to submit the selected value `this.form.submit()`

Comment: this does not work for me ... the result is the same as my original code

Comment: @AndreasSoraru understood what was wrong, answer should now be correct

Comment: yes ... thats it ... that works lika a charm ... thanks a lot

Comment: i would like to know if that will also work if i add a second dropdown to the form ... or should i open a new question for that?

Comment: of course it will work, just make sure only one dropdown is used for submit, best the last one, or you might add submit button and remove submit function from dropdown, think about usability, check out some existing form samples on internet :)

Comment: in fact i will need a solution where both of the drop-downs can do a submit ... or would it be better to put that into two seperate forms ... each one with a dropdown?

Comment: @AndreasSoraru think about this for future, you'll have eventually tens of different dropdowns with filters, each of them submits info = user needs to reload page each parameter separately = user unfriendly UI, it is usually way better to add multiple dropdown selectors and one submit only so user can set each filter as he want and the run just one query, this will save bandwidth as well as your servers computing power

Comment: Yeah ... thats true ... so i will have to add something like an "Apply filter" button  to get this done .... by the way ... would there be any way to do that without reloading the page ... something like just refreshing the table with the results? ... Actually it looks like that -> https://land-dinslaken.de/unsere-buchreihe

Comment: in php you need to refresh page, if you used javascript/jquery or something like that then you can just query the DB and update the result table with new vars

Comment: would you be so kind and provide me a small sample code or a link to something that matches my needs in some parts?

Answer (score 0):

The following works as requested, no need for form tag.

The first line is for demo, how to use the parameter that is passed.

```
<h1>Got <?php echo isset($_GET['sorttype'])? $_GET['sorttype'] : 'no value selected yet'; ?></h1>

    <select name="sortmode" onchange="location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value; "  style="margin-top:6px;">
       <option <?php if (isset($sorttype) && ($sorttype == 'Autor')) { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?php echo $url . '?sorttype=Autor' ?>">Autor</option>
       <option <?php if (isset($sorttype) && ($sorttype == 'Erscheinungsjahr')) { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?php echo $url . '?sorttype=Erscheinungsjahr' ?>">Erscheinungsjahr</option>
       <option <?php if (isset($sorttype) && ($sorttype == 'Herausgeber')) { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?php echo $url . '?sorttype=Herausgeber' ?>">Herausgeber</option>
       <option <?php if (isset($sorttype) && ($sorttype == 'Region')) { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?php echo $url . '?sorttype=Region' ?>">Region</option>
       <option <?php if (isset($sorttype) && ($sorttype == 'Titel')) { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?php echo $url . '?sorttype=Titel' ?>">Titel</option>
       <option <?php if (isset($sorttype) && ($sorttype == 'Stadt')) { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?php echo $url . '?sorttype=Stadt' ?>">Stadt</option>
       <option <?php if (isset($sorttype) && ($sorttype == 'Verlag')) { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?php echo $url . '?sorttype=Verlag' ?>">Verlag</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: thats almost like my code ... but it does just change the url ... it does not reload or refresh the page ...

Comment: TRUE. it changes the ```parameters``` - the URL MUST stay the same since you asked for RELOAD.

Comment: i want to make it automatically reload with the new parameters and run the complete code after the selection changed

Comment: @AndreasSoraru This is EXACTLY what you have! 1. You select/change the value 2. The page reloads 3. Executes new Title (you can replace it with any code you wish)

Comment: i am not sure what i am doing wrong but it does not work

Comment: i placed the code here -> https://land-dinslaken.de/weitere-heimatbezogene-literatur/ ... it is just the code you provided within a joomla category override

Comment: Seems that its doing the job. Using Javascript and AJAX is more appropriate. Please mark the answer as OK thanks.

Comment: No ... thats the code above from Ruli ... that works and is the actual version on the page with the link .. sorry ... forgot to mention that within the day